Why is apache-tvm available for python 3.10 but not python 3.12?
The package I want to install is apache-tvm. I checked it doesn't specify python version in pypi: https://pypi.org/project/apache-tvm/
I can use pip to install it in python 3.10:
> python --version
Python 3.10.13
> pip install apache-tvm
Looking in indexes: https://mirrors.pku.edu.cn/pypi/web/simple
...
install done

But in python 3.12, pip can't find the package:
> python --version
Python 3.12.2
> pip install apache-tvm
Looking in indexes: https://mirrors.pku.edu.cn/pypi/web/simple
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement apache-tvm (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for apache-tvm

I want to know why pip doesn't work in higher version. It may caused by some version check, but I can't find it on pypi project page.

See https://pypi.org/project/apache-tvm/#files -- latest binary distributions are for 3.11, and there's no source distribution at all. So we don't even need to look at which versions of Python the source says it's compatible with -- they didn't publish source to pypi at all.

Python 3.12.2 was released on February 6, 2024 and the latest release of apache-tvm was released in November 2023. Likely just a loss of support that is in the works to fix, but based on the dates that's what I'd expect.

It's not explicitly unsupported, and in this particular case inability to install via pypi doesn't tell us whether there is or isn't any bug to be fixed. It's just not published at all: they didn't publish a source distribution so anything relying only on pypi can only install binaries, and they didn't publish binaries newer than 3.11, so there's nothing available for pip to install into a 3.12 interpreter.

Thanks, I think your answer hit the point. Another question is: If the source and binary distribution are both provided(like in numpy https://pypi.org/project/numpy/#files), which one will be installed?
